# How to install oracle 10g in Fedora 19?

Tags: database, oracle10g

The link given in the official page of oracle for linux or fedora is broken. So, I am unable to install oracle 10g from the official website. Please give me any other ideas to install oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this database download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html):

> Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download.
>   The software is available as a media or FTP request for those
>   customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any
>   edition. To request access to these releases, follow the instructions
>   in Oracle Support Document 1071023.1 (Requesting Physical Shipment or
>   Download URL for Software Media) from My Oracle Support. NOTE: for
>   Oracle Database 10.2, you should request 10.2.0.1 even if you want to
>   install a later patch set. Once you install 10.2.0.1 you can then
>   apply any 10.2 patch set. Similarly, for 11.1 request 11.1.0.6 which
>   must be applied before installing 11.1.0.7. Patch sets can be
>   downloaded from the Patches and Updates tab on My Oracle Support.